# How to make .svg icon to react to disabled state and change it's color?

Tags: css, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

[image: What I want]

Basically when state of the icon is active we should show `.svg icon #1` and when it's disabled we should show `.svg icon #2` (basically show one of these two at any given time depending on a state of a button-icon).

The problem is that it's a custom .svg so I have to use Angular 1.x and `md-svg-icon="path\...\icon.svg"` and ideally I'd like to add only 1 icon to a static import and then change `fill: white` as a css property (I found this in other related questions), but here you can see I can't use fill for the whole picture (one part should remain red, only the other one should change the color) which complicates the solution.

The other option I thought about is to connect it with `ng-style` directive (and some `isIconDisabled` flag to controller), and add both of these icons to static import and then display either the 1st one or another. Does it make sense? I don't have that much experience with AngularJS unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the look of your icon by setting the style of specific elements of your svg icon. But this would be kind of a hassle and inconvenient as soon as the icon changes in the future.

I would go with your second option and use flags to control the icon for the states.
Basically you just toggle the icon with the state of your element (for example a button):

```
<button ng-click="doSmth()" ng-disabled="btnDisable">
  <img ng-src="{{activeButtonIconURL}}" ng-if="!btnDisable">
  <img ng-src="{{disabledButtonIconURL}}" ng-if="btnDisable"> 
</button>
```

Here is a working [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/GbiuonrNn2vBSjc7) of the above example.